# How to link to additional container without restarting?

Tags: docker

X-post from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/A180aHSlQRE

Let's say I run following command to link web container to db container-

```
docker run -d -P --name web --link db training/webapp python app.py
```

Now I want my web container to be linked to additional container WITHOUT restarting web container. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, once started you can't link the container to another container. But you can link a new container to the `web` container:

```
docker run -d -P --name myapp --link web <image> <command>
```

or you can link another `web` container to the db container:

```
docker run -d -P --name web2 --link db training/webapp python app.py
```

Having said that since your first `web` container is running you can also run:

```
docker inspect web
```

to find out the details of that container and see if you'd like to use them in your new container that you create.  Another thing you can try is to make your `web` container interactive so once you started it you can modify it at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is way to overcome this limitation.

What you can do in this situation is to add LINKED_CONTAINER_IP and LINKED_CONTAINER_NAME directly into /etc/hosts file of "HOST CONTAINER" using following procedure:

1. get the IP address of the running container which you want additionally to link into "host container" using

   `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' CONTAINERID`

directly from host

3 then add that ip with the name into `/etc/hosts` of "HOST CONTAINER" file as following

- first get interactive access into shall of running host container

  `docker exec -it CONTAINERID sh`
- once you get into shell prompt add line to `/etc/hosts` file using

  `echo "LINKED_CONTAINER_IP LINKED_CONTAINER_NAME" >> /etc/hosts`

  4. verify using `ping LINKED_CONTAINER_NAME`

Please note **this is temporary solution** which works only until any of containers are restarted in which case IP address may change and therefore resolving to LINKED_NAME will not work any more!